# Método toSring con un valor boolean en Java

Tags: java

A la hora de hacer un método toString: dentro de los valores que tengo, uno tiene que devolver un valor boolean (sí o no), del cual tengo la variable y la pongo y me da error... El error es que

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable tieneObra
  location: class Teatro
```

Y cuando lo ejecuto :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable tieneObra
```

¿Qué puedo poner?

Pongo el código:

```java
public boolean tieneObra(){
   
   return Teatro.Obra != null;}


public String toString(){
  return "Nombre del teatro: " + nombreTeatro + "; " + "Codigo del Teatro" + codigoTeatro +
          "; " + "Aforo: " + aforo + "; " + tieneObra + ";" + "Representando la obra:" +
          Obra + ";" + "Entradas vendidas: " + EntradasVendidas + " }"; 
          
}
```

El valor boolean es *tieneObra*.

Comment: Hablaste de un error, pero no de _cuál_ error. Pulsá en [edit] y agregá el error en cuestión.

Comment: @padaleiana ya lo he puesto, muchas gracias y perdón, soy novel

Comment: _tieneObra_ es una función ahí, no un bool... ¿Cómo obtenés el valor de una función si no la llamás? ;)

Comment: @padaleiana esa es la cosa que no se como hacerlo... por eso os he preguntado! Muchas gracias y disculpa por la falta de conocimiento

Comment: En realidad te di la respuesta en el comentario :) Basta con buscar "llamada a función Java" en tu buscador de preferencia. De hecho, tenés que buscar cómo convertir el valor devuelto a String.

Comment: @padaleiana me has liado mas jajaja, declaro una variable?

Comment: `tieneObra` no es una variable, es un método.... si no le pones `()` no va a funcionar.